# can someone explain this simplification for me??

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

Can someone tell me how $$−56−173\,\ln(11)+366\,\ln(13)−\left(\frac{105}2+20\,\ln(2)+366\,\ln(3)\right)$$
simplifies to $$\frac{-217}2−20\,\ln(2)−173\,\ln(11)+732\,{\rm arctanh}\left(\frac58\right)?$$

I just don't know how to get to the arctan part.

Comment: Between this and [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784429/can-someone-explain-this-simplification-for-me) it looks like you are just posting your homework for us to do for you.  Can you show your work so far?  That is, remove all the terms you have successfully matched to get the problem down to something more readable?

Comment: Well, $${\rm arctanh} (x) = {1\over2}\ln \left(1+x\over 1-x\right).$$ Does that help?

Comment: oh yeah! the problem is the integral from -3 to 4 of function (x^3-3)/((x+9)(x+7)) dx. I expanded the denominator to being x^2+16x+63. From there, I did long division on (x^3-3) divided by (x^2+16x+63). That resulted in x-16+((193x+1005)/((x+7)(x+9))). I did partial fractions from there on that remaining fraction. So it led to (A/(x+7)) + (B/(x+9)). I set that equal to 193x+1005 and I solved for A and B by using x=-7 and x=-9. I put in the numbers for A and B in place for that fraction within the integral. So I have the integral from -3 to 4 of the function x-16+(366/(x+9))-(173/(x+7)) dx.

Comment: from there I integrated it and input the bounds which resulted in (-56+366ln|13|-173ln|11|)-((105/2)+20ln|2|+366ln|3|) thanks to the earlier question on how to simplify the natural logs.

Comment: Consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\tanh^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$

$366\ln(13)-366\ln(3)=\frac{1}{2}(732ln(13)-732ln(3))=\frac{1}{2}\left(732\ln\left(\frac{13}{3}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(732\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{5}{8}}{1-\frac{5}{8}}\right)\right)=732\tanh^{-1}(\frac{5}{8})$

Comment: the equation that you posted, is that an identity?
also, I get the fact on 732ln(13/3) but I don't get how the 1/2 factors in?

Comment: @jennifer the equation is the definition of arctanh

Comment: oh okay I see. but I still don't understand how the answer resulted in arctanh(5/8)? Where did the 5 and the 8 come from?

Comment: @jennifer is it clear now?

Comment: yes thank you so much!!!!